# R: sprintf to pad decimal number with leading white spaces

Tags: r, formatting, string-formatting

I'm trying to pad a decimal number with leading white spaces using the `sprintf` function.

For example, I would like to convert the following vector:

```
a <- c(1, 1.123, -1.123, 123)
[1]   1.000   1.123  -1.123 123.000
```

to (padding = 4):

```
[1] "   1.00"   "   1.12"   "  -1.12"   " 123.00"
```

I tried with `sprintf("% 4.2f", a)` but it produces the following result:

```
[1] " 1.00"   " 1.12"   "-1.12"   " 123.00"
```

**Edit:**

I know that it works with integers, i.e. `sprintf("%4d", 123)` will produce `" 123"`, but I can't make it work with floating numbers.

Comment: the code you posted does not produce the outcome you claim...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I edited my original post to correct the code.

Comment: ok it runs now but other problems persist, R will not print that outcome vertically with the code you provided...I'm assuming thats not a problem for you?

Comment: @Hack-R I would prefer to rely on `sprintf` if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `%7.2f`.  7 characters total, 2 to the right of the decimal.

```
sprintf("%7.2f", a)
# [1] "   1.00" "   1.12" "  -1.12" " 123.00"
```

Thanks for the hint from @Jota, we removed the space before `7.2f`.